# Migrating from React Native to Native (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm using AsyncStorage massively in my react native app before, and I want to migrate the app to Native Android. I don't need the data, I just want to delete them, How to do it? Or is it okay to ignore the data saved in user memory? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you wondering how to delete saved data when the user updates to a new (native) version of the app?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean